# How can I use google earth in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, geocoding, google-earth, mapkit

now I make iPhone Application (iOS4) by Xcode 4.
I know MKMap Kit for using googleMap to making iOS Apps.
But I wanna use **google earth on iPhone App**, because the motion is really smooth and pics are nice to enjoy to see.

I want to know how, what framework to use google earth in iOS 4 app.

I am a beginner of iPhone coding.

Comment: there is no any framework like google earth in ios

Comment: thanks for your answer.

then, is there any other way to use google earth on iOS without Framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no Google Earth framework available to use. There is a third-party framework, though that mimics a 3D-globe behaviour by clevercoding.com: http://www.clevercoding.com/iPhone3Dglobe.php

Comment: oh, impossible.
thank you for your answer!

I know Goole Earth framework is not available.
But I want to make Google Earth-based app in iPhone.

I'll try to find any other way!

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt api on iOS for google earth but what you can do is that you can change the map type to "Hybrid" from either the interface builder or programmatically .

From Interface builder

- Select ur MapView -->> go to attribute inspector and change its type to Hybrid.

or programmatically you can do it by:

Make an IBOutlet to your map.
     IBOutlet MKMapView *userMap;

Next, in your viewDidLoad method do this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad  
{  
     [super viewDidLoad];  
     userMap.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;  
}
```

and this will at the very least give you a view like google earth ..

Comment: A hybrid map doesn't even come close to a 3D globe.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply!
referring to your answer, I could view a googleEarth-like-map.

I can reach a step closer to my ideal!
thank you!

Comment: yes, I want to get 3D globe view.
But I know hybrid is the best way now i can try.

mmm... on Android, we can see 3D map in Google Map.
meaning, I heard that users can change view angle, so possible for use to see globe from 0 - 90 angle.